# SENDER_ID Error While Creating Hybrid App Using Forcedroid

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, hybrid

I created a few hybrid apps before and they got created and are running just fine. 
But, When I tried to create an app today it is giving me an Error: Variable(s) missing: SENDER_ID
As shown below.
[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a while, I found the solution to the error above.

Though you get the error, a cordova project is created.
Navigate to that project's directory in command prompt and type the following commands, and your project is fixed and ready to go.

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

After the above command's process is finished, type in the command below

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin
```

Thats it, Your project is good to go. :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue is caused by the recently (8th March) release of the 1.6.0 version of the Phonegap Push Plugin. This release now [requires the SENDER_ID to be](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/03/08/phonegap-plugin-push-1-6-0/) set on installations (seems an odd idea to me).

The SDK folk fixed this on the 12th in this [PR](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/pull/177) and is available in the master branch of the cordova plugin repo. The fix is to hard set the use of the 1.5.0 version of the push plugin.